# Deferred length character array pointer error with gfortran

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran, character, gfortran

I have two deferred length character arrays in gfortran.  I allocate one of them, and then point the other one to it.  The pointer variable has the correct character length, but not the correct array size.  The program terminates with an error when trying to access the information in the pointer.

I'm testing this with:
GNU Fortran (MacPorts gcc8 8.2.0_2) 8.2.0

The code below works fine with Intel Fortran on Windows.

```
program test

  character(len=:), pointer, dimension(:) :: charvara
  character(len=:), pointer, dimension(:) :: charvara_ptr

  allocate(character(len=10) :: charvara(3))
  charvara(:) = '0123456789'
  print *, len(charvara)
  print *, size(charvara)
  print *, charvara

  charvara_ptr => charvara
  print *, associated(charvara_ptr, charvara)
  print *, len(charvara_ptr)
  print *, size(charvara_ptr)
  print *, charvara_ptr

  print *, 'end'

end program test
```

I would expect the length, size, and contents of charvara_ptr to be the same as charvara, but instead I get the following:

```
          10
           3
 012345678901234567890123456789
 T
  1708412736
           3
test(66553,0x7fff9e47c380) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=140734901800960) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Memory allocation failure in xrealloc

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x104fbe65f
#1  0x104fbeecd
#2  0x104fbf057
#3  0x104fbe0c9
#4  0x1050cc8e4
#5  0x1050c30db
#6  0x1050c8af5
#7  0x1050cbc6c
#8  0x1050cc712
#9  0x104fb3d80
#10  0x104fb3dde
```

Comment: This is a compiler bug which you can [report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) (searching first for previous).

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Did not find an existing bug report, so I created a [new one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89352)

Comment: The bug is fixed in the upcoming gcc/gfortran 9.1.  The patch has not been back ported to older branches.